# Quantity input change - capturing previous value

Tags: jquery

I try to prevent executing this line: `jQuery('#out1').append('success ');` if previous and current cart product quantity values are equal. In reality there will be AJAX request to update cart, but I don't want it to happen if `'change keyup mouseup'` was only because user clicked on input field without actually changing anything.

I wrote this code, but it works incorrectly, depending on change method current value can be assigned as previous or previous followed by current (in commented out test only current appears in this case).

```
var timeout;
var prevVal;

jQuery('div.mycart').on('change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function(){
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event  
    // if (prevVal == $(this).val()) return;
    jQuery('#out2').append(prevVal);
    if ($(this).val() == '') return;  
    prevVal = $(this).val();
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {   
         jQuery('#out1').append('success ');          
  }, 1000 );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8qg4kzu/

EDIT: I put this code on my staging website, both on Chrome and Firefox success only fires once, clicking on input field (not increment buttons) doesn't do anything. It's the same jQuery version. Whats wrong with jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating the logic. a simple change listener will do.

```js
$('input.qty').change(function(){
console.log('value' + $(this).val());
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: red;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycart">  
  <input type="number" id="quantity_123" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="425" name="cart_qty" value="1" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
<p id="out1"></p>
<p id="out2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: No, without keyup and mouseup both keyboard entry and increment buttons don't work on Firefox, but as I mentioned something is probably wrong with jsfiddle, because on staging website there is no action performed when I click with mouse cursor on input field.